# Creating a summary table from existing tables

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with several tables (the number of tables / columns can change depending upon user input)

Table 1

```
A   1   8   9
B   2   6   3
C   12  5   4
D   3   2   4
E   5   3   2
F   6   3   0
```

Table 2

```
A   2   16  18
B   4   12  6
C   24  10  8
D   6   4   8
E   10  6   4
F   12  6   0
```

I would like to create a summary table that merges all the tables and sums the values

Summary Table

```
A   3   24  27
B   6   18  9
C   36  15  12
D   9   6   12
E   15  9   6
F   18  9   0
```

I can get the data for a specific table using

```
var data = Array();

$("#table1 tbody tr").each(function(i, v){
    data[i] = Array();
    $(this).children('td').each(function(ii, vv){
        data[i][ii] = $(this).text();
    }); 
})
```

I need to build a function that I can feed in 2 arrays and it will sum them both. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rows and columns will always be same in count, here is a way you can do it by:

```js
let table1Rows = $("#table1 tr");
let table2Rows = $("#table2 tr");
let summaryRows = $("#summary tr");

table1Rows.each(function(row, t1Row) {
  $(t1Row).children('td').each(function(column, t1Column) {
    if (column !== 0) {
      let t1ColumnText = $(t1Column).text();
      let t2ColumnText = $($(table2Rows[row]).children('td')[column]).text();
      let sum = parseInt(t1ColumnText, 10) + parseInt(t2ColumnText, 10);
      $($(summaryRows[row]).children('td')[column]).text(sum);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Table 1</h3>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Table 2</h3>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Summary</h3>
<table id="summary">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Close, but there could be several tables so I wouldn't be able to declare table1Rows statically

Comment: @Lee -- doesn't matter. My code is just an example. You can create an array of table references and work with them.